# how to kill 2 processes in linux

Tags: process, background, fedora, kill

I have two programs running simultaneously ( in linux ) , with one running at the background. When i press ctrl+c , the prompt returns , but the processes seem to continue.. How to kill them both ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

use `pkill myprocess`. If not, check the pid of the background process using `ps -ef`, then use `kill -9 <pid>`. you can also use `pgrep myprocess` to find those pids.

Answer (score 0):

Background processes started from the same as your current shell are visible through job control as well.  In bash type "jobs" and you can kill %1 for example.